# Retrieve Data From Sql and Save it to PDF

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, pdf

Hi everybody Sorry maybe this questions asked many times but most of the answers not fit with me,Perhaps the lack of my understanding of what was write in these forums.

I am new in C# I want to retrieve Id in dropdown another control from SQL Database and when a user click an id and click the button which is create **PDF** then all the data from table show in column in pdf.table name is profile

table attributes are name,fathername,picture,gender,status,age etc

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you have? At the moment your question is way to broad IMO...

Comment: I don't understand how to code to retrieve id from data base and save all the table data which is selected id in to PDF

Answer (score 1):

Populating IDs in dropdown is easy. You can do that by choosing datasource.
For creating pdf, in the buttonclick event you can either use the inbuilt report viewer or any third party tools like ITextSharp.
You can read the selected id from dropdownlist as ddl.SelectedItem/ddl.SelectedValue

Comment: please will you solve it?? I am new. I used Itextsharp dll file to create pdf

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ID" 
            DataValueField="ID" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [ID] FROM [TABLENAME]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: The above code will populate IDs into your dropdown list